# Error Ionic al ejecutar aplicacion desde Linux

Tags: linux, ionic

Estoy tratando de crear mi primera aplicación en [ionic](/questions/tagged/ionic). Creo la app sin problemas pero cuando ejecuto *run* aparece este mensaje:

> Failed to load index.html

Y después que ionic abre mi navegador Firefos dice:

> try again later

***Captura de la consola***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Captura de la consola***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: traduce tu pregunta por favor, no sólo el título :D

Comment: okey, se me olvido

Answer (score 0):

En sistemas operativos basados en UNIX, siempre se tiene que ver el tema de permisos... Para este caso, ejecuta como root:

```
sudo su
ionic_run
```

Comment: no, no es eso, eso eso es un alias que yo he creado por comodidad

Comment: ¿Has ejecutado como root?